# 'Someway' vs 'somehow'?

Tags: differences

What's the difference between 'someway' and 'somehow'?

When I translate to my language (portuguese) on google translator, they translate the same. And on google I found only music lyrics.

Comment: "someway" isn't a word; "somehow" is.

Comment: @phoog It appears in some [dictionaries](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/someway) and [here](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/someway). and [here](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/someway).

Comment: @Catija so it does.  I have learned something new today.  I can't think of a sentence in which it would seem acceptable, however.

Comment: 1)Somehow, someway, I have to find a way out and up into the sunlight again.
2) But why pull the race card and act like somehow, someway this is a story about race. 3)
we’ve got to make money someway

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/it/definizione/inglese/someway

Comment: ***Someway: (often someways) informal , chiefly North American*** Somehow vs someway*: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=somehow%2C+someway&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomehow%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csomeway%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Maybe put it together so show what you are talking about is remote: somehow, someway, somewhen, somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm British. Today is the first time I have seen the word *someway*.

If you use Google Books Ngram Viewer, you will see that it does occur but its frequency is negligible in comparison to *somehow*.

The meaning appears to be the same.

Answer (score 2):

*Somehow* is short for "in some way not yet known." *Someway,* despite lacking formal recognition is just another way of saying the same thing. Perhaps it is even a bit clearer, eliminating the need to parse "how" as "way".

It is definitely a less established, informal word.

For Reference:

[Etymonline - Somehow](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=somehow)

> **somehow** (adv.) 1660s, "in some way not yet known," from some + how. First attested in phrase somehow or other.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow is about the process itself; "in some way" (which,  I suppose,  is the same as "someway" - though I find that to be a fringe usage) is about the results of the process. For example,  "Somehow we have to get him to change his behavior" versus "We have to get him to change his behavior in some way".  The former says the method to use is unclear, while the latter says the resulting change is unclear.